# Set Property Value on Master Page from Content Page (when using a base page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I created a few public string properties on my master page. I intially thought I could set them in the Page_Load of my content pages like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Master.Property1Title = "Test title";
}
```

This is not working... Is it because my content page uses a base page?

Comment: Do you have multiple Master pages?  Could your content page be inheriting from a Master page that doesn't have those public properties?

Comment: Yes, I have a few master pages. I made sure that my content page is inheriting from the master page with my new public properties.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to create the properties on the master page?

Comment: I found a really cool post from 2007 that tells you how to do it using an interface. http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/right-way-of-accessing-master-page.html I ended up going this route.

Answer (score 0):

You should to cast to your master page type.

```
var myMaster = Master as MyMasterPageClassName;

if(myMaster != null)
{
    myMaster.Property1Title = "Test title";
}
```

Comment: This is not working it still isn't finding my public properties. Should setting these properties in my base page and then have my master page access the values from the base page instead?